# JAVASCRIPT: Ordenar lista HTML por nome e por idade

Tags: javascript, html, order

Boa noite,

Preciso ordenar uma lista de frases em HTML por nome do usuário ou pela idade, conforme o botão que for clicado. Como posso fazer isso?

Segue abaixo, uma versão mais clara do código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="master">
        <button onClick="orderName()">Ordenar por nome</button>
        <button onClick="orderIdade()">Ordenar por idade</button>
        <br/>
        <ul id="lista-usuarios">
            <li>João é homem e possui 23 anos"</li>
            <li>Ana é mulher e possui 19 anos"</li>
            <li>Ricardo é homem e possui 32 anos"</li>
            <li>Fernanda é mulher e possui 25 anos"</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        function orderName() {
            var list = document.querySelector("#lista-usuarios");
            console.log("Ordenado por nome");
        }
        function orderIdade() {
            var list = document.querySelector("#lista-usuarios");
            console.log("Ordenado por idade");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

**Caso necessário, [essa é a versão completa](https://jsfiddle.net/f87bu3wx/16/).**

As frases são montadas a partir do array `users` (como é visto no link acima). Consegui fazer os filtros funcionarem, então optei por reduzir o código, pra facilitar.

Como **preciso que a ordenação funcione junto com os filtros**, entendi que talvez fosse necessário pegar a lista a partir do `HTML`, pra manter os filtros ao ordenar (nas minhas tentativas, se eu pegasse a partir do array, teria que limpar a lista, o que eliminaria o filtro).

Comment: Da onde se monta essa lista?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta explicando melhor como a lista é obtida, @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando `.map()`, `.sort()` e `.filter()` você consegue ordenar. Veja que no caso da idade foi preciso usar expressão regular com `.match()` para pegar apenas o valor numérico da idade (não pode haver outro número no texto senão a idade!):

```js
function orderName() {
   var list = document.querySelector("#lista-usuarios"); // seleciona a UL
   var list_lis = list.querySelectorAll("li"); // seleciona as LIs
   var nova_list = ''; // crio uma variável vazia que será usada para construir uma nova lista ordenada
   [].map.call(list_lis, function(a){ // mapeio as LIs retornando o texto
      return a.textContent;
   }).sort().filter(function(a){ // ordeno em ordem alfabética e retorno o texto ordenado
      nova_list += '<li>'+a+'</li>'; // concateno o texto construindo uma nova lista
   });
   
   list.innerHTML = nova_list; // substituo o conteúdo da UL pelos novos LIs ordenados
  
   console.log("Ordenado por nome");
}

function orderIdade() {
   var list = document.querySelector("#lista-usuarios");
   var list_lis = list.querySelectorAll("li");
   var nova_list = '';
   [].map.call(list_lis, function(a){
      return a.textContent.match(/\d+/); // aqui eu seleciono apenas a idade
   }).sort().filter(function(a){ // ordeno em ordem numérica (o .sort() faz isso automaticamente)
      nova_list += '<li>'+a.input+'</li>'; // concateno o texto
   });
   
   list.innerHTML = nova_list;
  
   console.log("Ordenado por idade");
}
```

```html
<div id="master">
  <button onClick="orderName()">Ordenar por nome</button>
  <button onClick="orderIdade()">Ordenar por idade</button>
  <br/>
  <ul id="lista-usuarios">
      <li>João é homem e possui 23 anos"</li>
      <li>Ana é mulher e possui 19 anos"</li>
      <li>Ricardo é homem e possui 32 anos"</li>
      <li>Fernanda é mulher e possui 25 anos"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getNumber(str) {
 return +str.textContent.match(/\d/gi).join('')
}

function orderIdade() {
  const list = document.querySelector("#lista-usuarios");
  const listChildren = [...list.children];
  const numbers = listChildren.map(item => getNumber(item));
  const listOrder = numbers
    .sort()
    .map(number => listChildren.filter(item => getNumber(item) === number));
   list.innerHTML = listOrder.map(item => `<li>${item[0].textContent}</li>`).join('');
}

function orderNome() {
  const list = document.querySelector("#lista-usuarios");
  const listChildren = [...list.children]
   .map(item => item.textContent)
    .sort();
  list.innerHTML = listChildren.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('');
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista-usuarios">
  <li>João é homem e possui 23 anos</li>
  <li>Ana é mulher e possui 19 anos</li>
  <li>Ricardo é homem e possui 32 anos</li>
  <li>Fernanda é mulher e possui 25 anos</li>
</ul>

<button class='btn' onClick="orderNome()">Ordenar pelo nome</button>
<button class='btn' onClick="orderIdade()">Ordenar pela idade</button>
```

Comment: Ficou bem legal usando ES6.

Comment: Então... eu não entendi bem o `.match(/\d/gi)` na função `getNumber()`. Qual o papel das barras, do `d` e do `gi`?

Comment: Então meu amigo, usamos uma expressão regular para pegar somente os números de uma String. O ***//*** é uma expressão regular no seu formato literal. o ***\d*** indica que eu quero apenas números. O ***gi*** nesse caso não faz muita diferença, ele faz mas sentido com textos. Você colocar ***\d+*** é mais indicado, o ***+*** ai indica pelo 1 ou mais vezes.
Vou deixar esses dois links que vão te ajudar a entender melhor essas dúvidas.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions 
https://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-em-javascript/37015