# Javascript, lista em ordem alfabética não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Esse código é para criar um lista dos posts do blogger em ordem alfabética. É exibido o titulo e a imagem do post.
Eu alterei esse código para mudar a posição da imagem e do titulo e criar `class`, a imagem aparecia depois do titulo, tudo fica em uma unica linha, texto e imagem.
Porém depois da mudança a lista deixou de ser em ordem alfabética, eu não consegui identificar o erro, ainda estou aprendendo javascript.
Essa é a parte que eu alterei:

```
          a1E.href = url;
          a1E.textContent = title;
          a1E.className += "aclass";
          postImage.src = imageThumb;
          postImage.className += "imclass"; 
          liE.appendChild(postImage);
          liE.appendChild(a1E);
```

Antes de alterar:

```
              a1E.href = url;
              a1E.textContent = title;
              postImage.src = imageThumb;
              liE.appendChild(a1E);
              liE.appendChild(postImage);
```

codigo completo:

```
  var startIndex = 1;
  var maxResults = 150;
  var allResults = [];
  function sendQuery12()
  {
    var scpt = document.createElement("script");
    scpt.src = "/feeds/posts/summary/-/Series?alt=json&callback=processPostList13&start-index=" + startIndex + "&max-results=" + maxResults;
    document.body.appendChild(scpt);
  }
  function printArrayResults(root)
  { 
    //Sort Alphebetically
    allResults.sort(function(a, b){
      var a_string = a.children[0].textContent ;
      var b_string = b.children[0].textContent ;
      if(a_string < b_string) return -1;
      if(a_string > b_string) return 1;
      return 0;
    })
    var elmt = document.getElementById("postList13");
    for (index = 0; index < allResults.length; index++) {
      elmt.appendChild(allResults[index]);
    }
  }
  function processPostList13(root)
  {   
    var elmt = document.getElementById("postList13");
    if (!elmt)
      return;
    var feed = root.feed;
    if (feed.entry.length > 0)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < feed.entry.length; i++)
      {
        var entry = feed.entry[i];
        var title = entry.title.$t;
        var date = entry.published.$t;

        if( entry.media$thumbnail != undefined ){
          var imageThumb = entry.media$thumbnail.url ;
        } else {
          var imageThumb = 'https://i.imgur.com/PqPqZQN.jpg' ;
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++)
        {
          if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate")
          {
            var url = entry.link[j].href;
            if (url && url.length > 0 && title && title.length > 0)
            {
              var liE = document.createElement("li");
              var a1E = document.createElement("a");
              var postImage = document.createElement("img");

              a1E.href = url;
              a1E.textContent = title;
              a1E.className += "aclass";
              postImage.src = imageThumb;
              postImage.className += "imclass";

              liE.appendChild(postImage);
              liE.appendChild(a1E);



              //elmt.appendChild(liE);
              allResults.push(liE);

            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (feed.entry.length >= maxResults)
      {
        startIndex += maxResults;
        sendQuery12();
      } else {
        printArrayResults();
      }
    }
  }
  sendQuery12();
```

---

HTML: `<div><ul id="postList13"></ul></div>`

Comment: As `<li>` que vc está criando estão dentro de uma `<ul>`?

Comment: Sim está, eu coloquei o html errado, vou arrumar

Comment: Não seria `postList13` a id, como está no código?

Comment: Sim, coloquei errado de novo, agora está tudo certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme respondi **[neste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/310345/8063)**, você consegue reordenar as `<li>` em ordem alfabética usando `.map()`, `.sort()` e `.filter()`. O código abaixo irá fazer o trabalho, substituindo o HTML da lista por uma nova lista ordenada. Coloque-o após o `for` onde você está criando as `<li>`:

```
var lis = elmt.querySelectorAll("li"); // seleciona as LIs
var ordenada = ''; // crio uma variável vazia que será usada para construir uma nova lista ordenada

[].map.call(lis, function(a){ // mapeio as LIs retornando o HTML
   return a.textContent+a.outerHTML; // coloco o texto no início da LI
}).sort().filter(function(a){ // ordeno com .sort()
   ordenada += a.match(/<li>.*<\/li>/); // pego apenas a LI e concateno
});

elmt.innerHTML = ordenada; // substituo o conteúdo da UL pelos novos LIs ordenados
```

Comment: Eu mudei aqui, mas acho que fiz alguma coisa errada, porque não funcionou, pode me mandar com o código completo por favor? se possivel mantenha os comentarios

Comment: Eu realmente estava fazendo errado, acabei colocando dentro de `for`

Comment: Não funcionou, link do código em funcionamento no blogger: http://testenextdark.blogspot.com/p/teste.html

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu achei que tinha funcionado, mas acho que foi só um problema com o loading da pagina, quando recarreguei a pagina, continuou fora de ordem, mas obrigado por ajudar

Comment: sim eu sei usar o console pq?

Comment: Eu descobri o que está causando o problema, `liE.appendChild(postImage);` está vindo antes de `liE.appendChild(a1E);` e está sendo a ordem de acordo com a imagem, porém eu preciso que a imagem venha antes do titulo, é possível alterar isso sem mudar a ordem da lista?

Comment: Coincidentemente o link das imagens faziam com que ficassem em ordem, eu alterei as imagens, pode checkar o código e verá que é o mesmo.